# singleTask Activity no longer available

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app which launches into `Activity` 'A', which:
- on first launch, 'A' will launch 'B' followed by my singleTask `Activity` 'C'
- on subsequent launches, 'A' checks for a static flag on `Activity` 'C', and subsequently fires intent to bring back my singleTask `Activity` 'C'.

I am experiencing a problem whereby very occasionaly when re-launching 'A' it is taking me to 'B' instead of 'C'.  I have placed an abundance of log messages into my `Activity` 'C' methods (before calls to any `finish()`, `onStop`, `onDestroy`, `onPause`, `onDestroy` etc) in a hope of finding a moment in time when 'C' no longer exists... but nothing is logging.  The only possible cause I can think of is that I reference a third-party library from `Activity` 'C', which might be suffering from an error which is not passed back to my application. Could this be the case?

Comment: why not use `singleTop` ?

Comment: Because I don't want the possibility of creating a new instance of 'C', hence singleTask.

Comment: In general, if your app isn't started by other apps, you don't need `singleInstance` or `singleTask` launch modes to ensure that there is only one instance of an activity. There are other ways to do this. `singleTask` and `singleInstance` usually make more problems than they solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Comment: I already use these two flags in my intent to 'C' -- this is not my problem. I just want to try and understand why my singleTask Activity 'C' is disappearing on occasion.

Answer (score 0):

Android can kill your process at any time (when it isn't in the foreground). What you are probably seeing is exactly that. You've launched your app, ActivityA has launched ActivityB which has launched ActivityC. Now the user goes and does something else (like make a phone call or play Angry Birds). Later, he returns to your application (but your application's process was killed while it was in the background). Android creates a new process for your application and creates a new instance of Activity A. ActivityA checks the static variable in ActivityC, but it isn't set because ActivityC doesn't exist in the newly created process.

Comment: Related: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#always . Since sometimes Android will clear your activity stack when reopening your app.

Comment: "Android can kill your task process at any time" -- this is a bit concerning. What do I do when I want an app to remain available (and responsive) at all times? I already have alwaysRetainTaskState set true for Activity 'C'in my manifest.

Comment: If the app is in the foreground, Android won't kill it. Also, you can start a foreground service, this will usually prevent Android from killing your app. However, the user probably doesn't want your app taking up memory if it isn't doing anything.

Comment: A foreground service is out of the question. My concern is that I am getting absolutely no indication that my Activity is being ended. Are there any caveats I can exploit to ensure Android leaves the process in which my activity is running well alone? e.g. use of "android:process" against Activity 'C' whereby I can specify the same process name as an exported private service?

Comment: Nope. Android will kill your process if it is in the background whenever it wants to. There is nothing you can do about that (other than the things I have mentioned). Imagine what would happen if every application wanted to behave like this? Sorry, it is first and foremost a phone. You need to program defensively and be able to recover properly from the situation where Android killed your process. Of course, you could schedule an alarm that goes off every X minutes to see if your process is still alive and restart it if necessary, but that won't prevent your process from getting killed.

Comment: I am not entirely sure how I can program defensively (such as storing certain state information to file which pertains to my Activity when it is banished) when I do not know when it is killed.

Comment: You need to write important information persistently in `onPause()`. Your activity (and process) can be killed at any time after that, without warning.